# Running various ruby scripts from browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a set of tool that do not necessarily meet requirements to be called "web app"…

Those tools are usually run by me from command line, but sometimes the command needs to be run without my appearance at the crime scene. One option would be to just ssh to the box and run command remotely, second would be to CRON it, and third would be to use rails to run scripts from controllers or something like that. Is it possible to use some sort of rack application?

i.e:

```
require 'rack'

app = Proc.new do |env|
    ['200', {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, ['Hello world!']]
end

Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run app
```

Suggestions?

---

**Update:** Those are ruby scripts (i.e. something like `update_data.rb`, `generate_report.rb` etc.) I would like to have, say, a grid of icons, which would then open a form where the user would have to copy text from 1 field to another to eliminate "misfires" with time-intensive tasks, hit "EXECUTE" and see the output in, say, readonly text area)

Comment: What kind of commands do you want to trigger remotely?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to run scripts from a Rack or Sinatra app. What exactly is your question?

Comment: You can run any shell command from rails using backticks or the `system` command.  These could be wrapped up in controller actions in an admin controller, which requires an admin (eg you) to be logged in.

Comment: Updated the question. See newly added update.